# Azure API Manager. How to pass on the client certificate to backend request as part of request?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am looking for a way to do this.

Request -> Azure API Managemnet -> Azure API Managemnet verifies client certificate -> Azure API Managemnet forwards the request to backend server with x509 certificate.

In generaly in mutal certificate the certificate in terminated at TLS layer however in my case i want the certificate to go all the way to backend so that authenication can happen again at backend.

tried already
Mutual Authenication
Send-request policy
not looking for certificate in headers

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload your certificate to APIM under the Certificates -> Certificates (NOT CA Certificates) tab and attach it to the API by going to your API -> Backend -> Client Cert
[image]

This way you do not even need to send with the client request to APIM